# How to create simple music visualizer of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, rendering

I want to make a simple drum machine app for iPhone.

Now I'm designing archichecture for it. After some research I've decided to stick with methods described in Apple's [Audio Unit Hosting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for making playback system, these techniques are also presented in [Audio Mixer sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and their complexity is pretty fit my current ingeneering knowledge. (Mixig C++ and Objective-C code and using OpenAl looks frightening)

But I'm stuck at figuring out, how will I make a simple music visualizer, I plan to do standard spectrum visualizer showing vertical bars representing intensities of different frequency components.

1. I can't decide what is better to use to analyze raw sound data, that I will feed to sound I/O module, are there any Objective-C framework for that?
2. Also I don't know what type of graphic rendering to use? Can a simple visualizer be made using just Core Graphics or it is only a job for OpenGL? I want to achieve about 30 updates per second to make it look smooth?

Can you help me?

Comment: You can refer to the [Speak Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) code sample at least for the graphic rendering. It has a graphic visualizer with vertical bars..

Comment: I've been trying to work off of the Speak Here code but it's horribly outdated (latest build was when iPhone OS 2 was out!) and some of the old code actually throws warnings. I would bet that a lot of what they were doing could be accomplished with core graphics/animation. It seems crazy that I'm unable to find even one tutorial about making a visualizer for AVAudioPlayer (or any core audio framework).

Comment: I have successfully built Speak Here on Xcode4 with SDK 4.3, seens they have updated the sources. Anyways, you can certainly do the same with CoreGraphics, just a lot slower. Actually SpeakHere has two alternative methods of displaying that meter - only one of them uses OpenGL.

Comment: if you are more comfortable with C++ you should give http://openframeworks.cc a go - it's built for visualisations/interactive applications in mind and it has some nice examples to achieve what you aim for.

Comment: See here [https://github.com/prodia/AudioVisualizer](https://github.com/prodia/AudioVisualizer)

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to exploit cocos2d http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/
a very good framework enable developers to easily and quickly realize IOS graphical applications without dealing with OpenGL complexity.

You could for example create small png files representing rows of your FFT bins and animate them according to the music. This would be very easy with cocos2d because it already provides API to load png files and animate them.

bye